# Как программно вызвать обработчик события в JS?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!
Есть следующий код, которыйм добавляем обработчик клика по таблице:

```js
var tb = document.getElementById('htable');
tb.setAttribute('activeRowIndex', 0);
tb.addEventListener('click', onClick);
// В обработчике я следующим образом определяю куда кликнули
function onClick(e) {
  var row = getParentTag(e.target, 'TR');

  if (!row) {
    return;
  }
  idx = this.getAttribute('activeRowIndex');
  this.rows[idx].classList.remove('activeRow');
  row.classList.add('activeRow');
  this.setAttribute('activeRowIndex', row.rowIndex);
  id = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Как сразу после добавления обработчика эмулировать клик по первой строке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function onClick(e) {
  console.log("onClick", e.target.outerHTML, e.currentTarget);
}
var tb = document.getElementById('htable');
tb.setAttribute('activeRowIndex', 0);
tb.addEventListener('click', onClick);

tb.querySelectorAll("tr")[1].click(); // - клик по строке с индексом 1
```

```html
<table id="htable" border=1>
<tr>
<td>AAA</td>
<td>BBB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это работает, за что уже спасибо... Но только по нулевой. А по 1-ой? установка 'activeRowIndex' = 1 не помогает

Comment: Теперь то, что нужно! Благодарю)